# Distribution function for $X^2$

Tags: probability-theory

The probability density function for $X$ is defined as follows:

$f_X(x) = \frac12$ for $x \in (-1, 1)$, otherwise $0$

From that I can compute that the distribution function is:

$ F_X(x) = \frac{x+1}{2}$ for $x \in (-1, 1)$

But what do $f_{X^2}$ and $F_{X^2}$ look like? I can infer that:

$F_{X^2}(x) = P (X^2 < x) = P (X < \sqrt{x}) = F_X (\sqrt{x})$

which implies that:

$ F_{X^2}(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{2} $ for $ x \in (0, 1) $

But that is not a distribution function at all! Especially because it is not continuous. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've forgotten that $P(X^2<x)$ is not $P(X<\sqrt{x})$; it is $P(-\sqrt{x}<X<\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can't believe I've missed that!